# I am getting $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{2^{n}}=\frac{1}{16}$ but it is wrong according to wolfram alpha. Where is the error in my solution?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

This is my solution -
$$        \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{\left(n-1\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(n-1\right)x^{\left(n-2\right)} \\
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(n-1\right)x^{\left(n-2\right)}$$
Since this is absolutely convergent for $|x| < 1$, it is commutative. I haven't changed the lower bound from n = 1 to n = 2 since the term at n = 1 is 0 anyways.
$$        \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}x^{\left(n-2\right)}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{\left(n-2\right)} \\
        x^{2}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}x^{n}-x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{\left(n-1\right)} \\
        x^{2}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}x^{n}-x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}\\
        x^{2}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}x^{n}-x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
        \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}x^{n}=x^{2}\left(\frac{2}{\left(1-x\right)^{3}}\right)+x\left(\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}\right)\\
        \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}=\frac{1}{2^{3}}-\frac{1}{2^{4}}=\frac{1}{2^{4}}
$$

Comment: In the 3rd line from the bottom, it is not true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$. It is $\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Comment: From the second line to the last line,  $x^2(2/(1-x)3)=(1/4)2(8)=4$ because you are dividing by powers of $1/2$.  Similar with the other term.

Comment: @Riemann they differ by $1$ so they have the same derivative

Comment: In general if $P(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$, and $D$ stands for the differential operator, then if $\sum a_nx^n = f(x)$, we can write $\sum P(n) a_n x^n = P(xD) f(x)$.  Hence what you are looking for is $(xD)(xD) \dfrac{x}{2-x}$ evaluated at $x=1$.

Comment: $S=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. For $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we can substitute $1-x$ with $x$, then $S=\frac{2x^2}{x^3}+\frac{x}{x^2}=\frac{3}{x}=6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that while the second derivative can be written as

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2},$$

for $n \in \{0, 1\}$, the summand is zero:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2} = 0 + 0 + 2 + 6x + 12x^2 + \cdots.$$

Hence it is better to adjust the lower index of summation before continuing to manipulate the sum:

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right] = \sum_{n=\color{red}{2}}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}.$$  Then continuing with your approach,

$$\begin{align}
x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right] &= \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^2 x^n - \sum_{n=2}^\infty nx^n \\
&= -x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^n + x - \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^n - x \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^n - x \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right].
\end{align}$$

This implies
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^n = \frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3} + \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}.$$

However, there is a much more direct way to do the calculation:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$
implies
$$x \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$
which implies
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right]\right] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^{n-1}.$$

All that is left is to compute the LHS:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right]\right] = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\right] = \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}.$$  Then multiplying everything by $x$ gives the desired result:

$$\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^n.$$

---

It would seem that your computation is mostly correct, except you have made an arithmetic error in the very last line.  You should have
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \frac{2}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^3} = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{(1/2)^3} = \frac{16}{4} = 4,$$ and
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 4 = 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked at your arguments. The terms in your summation are all positive. Simply looking at the first 2 terms: $n =1$, gives $1/2$ and $n=2$ gives $2^2/2^2=1$ and so the sum should be $>3/2$, and can't be $1/16$.